# SQL Reporting Services - Export to Excel - why "Custom" formats?

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have a SQL Reporting Services report which contains monetary values, shown without the currency symbol (ie. 1,234.56). I export this report to Excel and, should I then choose to re-format these as currency values, and press the "Currency" format button, I get "$ 1,234.56".

Ok... except I'm in the UK and my regional settings specify "£" as the currency symbol. If I just fire up Excel, type in 1234.56 and hit the currency format button, I get "£ 1,234.56" - so it doesn't appear to be the default settings for Excel.

I looked more carefully at the exported Excel sheet and noticed that the values are formatted with a "Custom" format, specifically "[$-1010809]#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)". I'm not sure what the "1010809" is *([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076487/excel-number-formatting-with-locale-how-does-it-work)). (This may not be related)*

It turns out that the "Currency" button applies the "Accounting" format, but that, in the spreadsheet exported from SSRS, is a custom format of "*("$"* #,##0.00*);*("$"* (#,##0.00);*("$"* "-"??*);*(@_)". This presumably accounts for the dollar symbol.

Is there not a way to have the exported spreadsheet not use "custom" US dollar formats for currency values ? I have looked at the report and tried to find some setting or property that says "English (US)" or something similar, but found nothing.

Comment: This is using SSRS 2005 (?) and Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The language can be changed for the report itself in the Properties palette window (**not** the "Report Properties" dialog.) In this window, in the localization section, there is a Language option.

Make sure this is set appropriately: en-GB

Comment: Thanks. From an SSRS point of view, these are just numbers and are formatted using "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)". Its when they get to Excel that I say "these are currencies", and the strange custom formats are applied. The report itself doesn't show currency symbols, but once in Excel, the user might choose to apply them.

Comment: As an experiment, what do you get if you do specify a currency format in the report? If that is $, then maybe you can switch the locale on the server. This may change the locale that is set in the exported Excel spreadsheets.

Comment: Hmmm... doesn't really help. Upon changing the SSRS format string to be "c2", I had some fields with $ and some with £ - the ones with $ had a Language property of "English". I changed that to be "Default" and all my fields have £. I uploaded to the report server, ran the report (all £) and exported to Excel. Still all £ because the cells use a custom format of "[$-1010809]£#,##0.00;-£#,##0.00". I then pressed the currency button and the fields flip to $ using the custom accounting format noted before.

Comment: I am about to massively change, or delete, my answer. The language might be specified in the report: Properties window, make sure Report is selected in top dropdown, then in the localization section, look for the language box. What do you see there? I'm goign to edit my answer to change it to propose this.

Comment: I looked at the report properties, and the "Language" was already set to "English (United Kingdom)". I changed it to "Default" but that made no functional difference.

Comment: I just saw your comment about the SSRS version. I strongly encourage you to upgrade to SSRS 2008R2 for Reporting Services functionality. There have been many changes: SSRS 2005 was just the second release of the product. But other than that, I'm out of ideas. I'll delete this answer in a day or two.

Comment: Hi, just double checked and setting the language of the report (to "English (United Kingdom)" vs. "Default") does make a difference - it creates 809 custom formats (English UK) instead of 409 formats (English US). Other than that, still get $ signs when applying "currency/accounting" format.

Comment: Just did some more trawling and it seems that its more "correct" to set the language of the report to "=User!Language". Not that it helped though !